# How can I retain original dimensions after adding thickness?

Tags: 3d-printing

After scaling (3D prep), the clean object (0 NonMan) has the dimensions as expected:

[image: original dimensions]

When applying solidify modifier with thickness 1mm, the entire object (lid) is scaled up:

[image: object scaled up]

Original sizing (close to) is retained with thickness 0.05mm, however this would not be reasonable since I need some minimal structural strength.

Is there a clean way to retain the original geometry without rescaling everything?

Comment: try changing the offset value

Comment: @Chebhou That did it (offset 1), thank you. Also found out that, flipping normals on the top part added thickness inside rather than outside, in order to keep the original size.

Comment: Yes, that generally means the normals were inverted. You could use the offset value to control the direction of the solidify, but I guess fixing the normals is the best way.